# Rayleigh-Plateau instability and optic

Tags: optics, fluid-dynamics, geometric-optics

Let a liquid jet fall onto a surface. If the contact point is illuminated by a lase beam,
rings of light around the jet can be observed . (pic.1)
[image]

and we know it that the reason of this phenomenon is Rayleigh-Plateau instability at all and also we did a lot of researches about it and found out the fluid theory of this phenomenon perfectly . (pic.2) 
but we don't know the optic theory and it details perfectly. help me by answer this question ...

[image]

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

[Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law) tells you the angles when a beam of light passes across a surface from air into water or water into air. It tells you that a beam at grazing incidence inside water will be totally internally reflected. At steeper angles, light will exit into air.

It would appear that you have pointed the laser upward. The jet of water is largely cylindrical. In most places, light strikes the walls of the cylinder at grazing incidence, and is reflected back inside.

Near the bottom, the cylinder curves. It forms shapes like a stack of spheres. Near the top of each sphere is a ring shaped band where the surface bends inward. Light strike it at a steep enough angle to escape.

You can see similar effets when you look at the edge of a glass or plastic sheet. See http://studiorob.blogspot.com/2010/11/edge-glow-acrylic-plastic.html or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kuaH3EHeSg

Comment: if you have Attention ,you will find out that the rings make between spheres . why ?

Comment: I don't know the details of how the laser is pointed, and I can't really see where the rings are from the photo. But I would expect the rings to be where the surface curves inward. That would be the top of the spheres or the bottom of the neck between spheres.